# Qt animation - member doesn't exist

Tags: c++, qt

This code:

```
 QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine;

     QState *state1 = new QState(machine->rootState());
```

I'm getting an error:
C:\Users..\Animated_Button\main.cpp:13: error: 'class QStateMachine' has no member named 'rootState'

Comment: As it complains, it has no member named `rootState()`. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstatemachine.html

Comment: Perhaps you should check the documentation for `QStateMachine`?

Comment: @Mahesh hi, but I took this code from here (last example):http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtanimationframework/animation.html, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check which version you're using against the version the example is based on.

Comment: @smallB - The qt version in the examples you gave is 4.4. But the latest is 4.7 for which I gave the class reference.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstatemachine.html), `QStateMachine` has no method named `rootState`. According to [this](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/07/23/qstatemachines-a-state-too/), it was removed at one point. The article states this:

> QStateMachine::rootState() is gone; the state machine now is the root state.

So the code you have comes from an outdated source. You should try doing this:

```
 QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine;

 QState *state1 = new QState(machine);
```

Comment: hi, did that, now I'm getting an error:  error: 'QState::QState(const QState&)' is private

Comment: @smallB That doesn't make any sense since the code I gave you uses a pointer, not a reference. Are you _sure_ you're using my code?

Comment: no, I'm sorry I didn't use your code, ok now WITH YOUR CODE I'm getting:  error: 'class QState' has no member named 'setPropertyOnEntry'

Comment: @smallB Again, according to the doc, you should use `assignProperty` instead.